# Generate random number and string after submition of form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create application win forms, where after submit the all detail generates random number and string. after generating random number then save  it in SQL  database.
so tell me how to generate combination of random number and random string.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You need separate String and integer?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of generating random number and a string, you should use [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx). That will be unique as well.

```
string val  = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Comment: Simple and great way to generate a random string

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public string RandomString (Random r, int len)
{
    string str
         = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while ((len--)> 0)
        sb.Append(str[(int)(r.NextDouble() * str.Length)]);

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()` or `DateTime.Now.ToFileTime().ToString()` to generate random number.

Answer (score 0):

why not use session id instead of generating randoms